# AutoHotkey Multiple GUI failing to update Text from Timer value

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a On Screen Display with a count-down in the mouse-position every time I press a key.
So far, I was able to make multiple  GUIs in the Mouse position every time I press the key and set up a Timer. But for some reason, I'm only capable of updating the last GUI created, even accessing it thru the Remarks.

```
Tabs := 0
Tab_OSD := 0
count := 0
return    
F7::
        CreateGUI("Gui" . Tabs)
        SetTimer, Tick, 1000
        Tabs++
        
        ;Tab_OSD := Tabs - 1
        ;Loop, %Tab_OSD%{
        ;   GuiControl, Text, % "Gui" . A_Index . "", % "" . count . ""
        ;   ;MsgBox, % "Iteration number is  Gui" . A_Index . " and " . count
        ;}
    return
    
    
    CreateGUI(nome) {
        MouseGetPos, StartX , StartY
        StartX:=StartX-15
        StartY:=StartY-15
        
        Gui, % nome . ": New"
        Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow
        Gui, Color, 000001
        Gui, Font, s12
        WinSet, TransColor, 000001
        Gui, % nome . ":Add", Text, cReD , %nome%
        Gui, % nome . ":Show", x%StartX% y%StartY% NoActivate
    }
    
    Tick:
        count++
        Gosub, UpdateOSD
    return
    
    UpdateOSD:
        Tab_OSD := Tabs - 1
        Loop, %Tab_OSD%{
            GuiControl, Text, % "Gui" . A_Index . "", % "" . count . ""
            ;MsgBox, % "Iteration number is  Gui" . A_Index . " and " . count
        }
    return
```

When I try to update the GUIs from the F7:: block (commented), it updates the last GUI. But when I try the same Loop on UpdateOSD, it don't update any Text.

If anyone can give me some light, I would be thankfull.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to make it work. It was missing a control variable in each GUI to update the text.

Another problem was that the name and control variable were being created on a function who didn't allow to use the variables out of that block.

Don't know if I could solve this another way, but creating the GUI on the trigger solved it.

I've also implemented a limit for the counter and Destroy the GUI when it's done.

```
Tabs := 1
count := 0
return


F7::    
    MouseGetPos, StartX , StartY
    StartX:=StartX-40
    StartY:=StartY-40
    
    Gui, % "Gui" . Tabs . ": New", 
    Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow
    Gui, Color, 000001
    Gui, Font, s16
    WinSet, TransColor, 000001
    Gui, % "Gui" . Tabs . ":Add", Text, % "vCtrl" . Tabs . " cReD", 00
    Gui, % "Gui" . Tabs . ":Show", x%StartX% y%StartY% NoActivate
    Tmp%Tabs% := 0
    
    SetTimer, Tick, 1000
    Tabs++
    
return
    

Tick:
    count++
    Gosub, UpdateOSD
return

UpdateOSD:
    TabOSD := Tabs - 1
    Loop, %TabOSD%{
        Tmp%A_Index%++
        if (Tmp%A_Index% > 45){
            Gui, % "Gui" . A_Index . ": Destroy"
            Tmp%A_Index% := 0
        }
        
        Tempo := Tmp%A_Index%
        GuiControl, % "Gui" . A_Index . ":", % "Ctrl" . A_Index . "" , %Tempo%
    }
    count := 1
return
```